# postgres sql database Column value is [null]

Tags: database, postgresql, null, nestjs, typeorm

I am am using nestjs & typeorm to query

```
//this is my model(interface)
    export interface Product {
        id?:number,
        
        name?:string,
    }
```

this is my entity.ts

```
@Entity('product')
export class ProductEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    @Column({ type:'text',nullable:true })
    name:string;

    @Column({type:'timestamp',default:() => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'})
    createdAt:Date;

}
```

[image]

the name column value is Null

This is what I call using postgress,

[image]

did anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Fix what? If there are NULL values, you will get them in your result. You can prevent that by defining the column as not nullable.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYyzy.png , I send post request with 'name' value but it doesn't save it.

Comment: Sorry, your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a text payload to the backend. It should be a JSON payload.
Use the dropdown menu to select `JSON` and the issue will go away.

[image]